# Volume of the overlap between 2 spheres

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

There are 2 spheres one with a radious "r1" and an other with the radious "r2". These spheres overlap to create a shape with 2 faces and 1 edge called a disk. The distance between the center of each face on a disk is "d". One can calculate the volume of a disk using "r1", "r2", and "d". What is the formula to calculate the disk's volume with the values of "r1", "r2", and "d"?[This image is a model of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEYGn.png)

Comment: The formula can be obtained algebraically, but it's a mess. What do you need it for?

Comment: It has been two years since I came up with the question and I'd really like to know the answer. I tried splitting the disk to use the "disk integration formula" from calculus 2 but, It is too hard to solve for the intersection of the circles to find the volume of each cut off section of the circles. I tried asking my professors, but they said it is too hard. I tried finding the formula but all I could find was the cut off of a sphere and the conjoined cutoffs of 2 spheres but no formula for the volume of 2 overlapping spheres based on the overlap itself.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: What do you _need_ it for?

Comment: I don't need it. But i would really like to have it. I was hopping someone from this site could figure it out.

Comment: I can give you a formula, but once you see that it's a nightmare, then what?

Comment: Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Volumes_of_union_and_intersection_of_two_intersecting_spheres

Comment: The center distance $c$ is necessary.  Follow this guidance  http://i66.tinypic.com/sc83s5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html) of which the derivation can be found on that page, the volume is

$$V=\frac{\pi(r_1+r_2-D)^2(D^2+2D(r_1+r_2)-3(r_1^2+r_2^2)+6r_1r_2)}{12D}$$

where $D$ is the distance between two centers.

The volume is obtained by adding the volumes of two spherical caps.

If they intersect, then

$$D= (r_1-d)+d+(r_2-d)=r_1+r_2-d$$

Comment: That "d" is between the centers of the circles not the distance between the centers of the 2 faces crated by the overlap of the spheres.

Comment: This is the answer. for all not r1 = r2.